# New ubuntu install / Partitoning

Tags: partitioning

i have a none booting vista on one hard drive, will installing Ubuntu on a partition let me see both Ubuntu & vista on start up? would it repair vista enough to use or rather not overwrite any info????? newbie mbr/grub/bootloader???

i also had remove sata hd to boot from usb into ubuntu, will this cause any problems reconnecting before installing ubuntu

thanks

Comment: You removed the SATA HD to boot to USB? How will you install onto the hd. You should turn the PC off, reconnect the SATA. Turn on and enter the bios menu (the key to do so is different on different PCs it will tell you "Press *KEY* for setup press that). Once in the bios menu there should be an option called boot order. Using the keys listed at the bottom of the screen you need to move USB above SATA. Now it will try USB before it tries SATA.

Answer (score 1):

> will installing Ubuntu on a partition let me see both Ubuntu & vista on start up

Yes, see it yes. But if Vista is broken Ubuntu/Grub will not fix it. Grub will error out after selecting Vista forcing you to reboot.

> would it repair vista enough to use or rather not overwrite any info

Ubuntu will never fix a Windows operating system. And the installer will overwrite Vista if -you- tell it to do so.

If you have hardware related problems installing Ubuntu will not fix those, if you have problems with a Microsoft version you need Windows tools to fix that problem.

You need to treat Ubuntu as a separate operating system that has nothing to do with Windows. Besides that Ubuntu will let you see the windows partitions and copy files over from it. But on a system level you need the operating system itself.

Comment: there is also a windows recovery partition would grub allow me to boot from it?

Comment: No, but those tend to be activated when you press a key combo during boot.

Comment: so pretty much without a vista recovery disk the windows is useless

Comment: Yes but that is the nature of Windows... I had to re-install someones machine without a drivers disc once. That was one hell I never want to go through. After 1st time use of windows you should always make a recovery disc :(

Comment: so if i install Ubuntu to a partition then i could recover any files i have from the hard drive currently its grayed out

Comment: Yes but it requires a working hard disc ;) Ubuntu will even include it automatically for you in the file browser as a partition

Answer (score 0):

> would it repair vista enough to use or rather not overwrite any info

If the problem is very simple (such as you somehow removed the boot flag from the vista a drive) then maybe. But probably not. If vista itself is broken this will not fix it.

The best option for you here is to plug back in the SATA drive (see my comment on your question). Boot to USB. You should be able to mount your vista partition (open the file browser and click on the Vista drive). You should be able to get to your files. If you can get to the files you can back them up to another a different HDD or to an external drive.

Now you have your files. You are safe to start "abusing" the vista partition to try to get it running. Or to shrink the partition and put ubuntu dual boot on. But probably the best option if you have your files backed up is a clean install. Either clean Ubuntu (good idea) or clean Vista (probably a bad idea, it was always an unstable operating system which is no longer in mainstream support, if you really want to use Windows it may be worth switching up to Windows 7).

Final piece of advice. What ever operating system you choose. Do not have your files on the same partition as your system. This way how ever much your system screws up you can always do a clean install without loosing any files.

Comment: thanks for the help, im unable to enter BIOS, disconnecting the hard drive was the only way to boot Ubuntu, although reconnecting the hard drive while Ubuntu is running works - the install See's the drive.

Comment: ideally i would like to just use Ubuntu, although the windows based programs i use might not work, does wine work for everything?there is only a bronze rating unless i use mint???

Comment: is there any way of someone remote fixing this issue for me? i have paypal?

Comment: I am not sure about remote fixing (I don't know how). What stope you getting into the bios?

Comment: the f2 have never worked, since i got the pc

Comment: The F2 key on they keyboard or F2 for bios, what is the laptop make/model?

Comment: on start up ive never been able to enter bios,and the screen is broke so i have a external monitor plugged that only shows on windows vista emblem

Comment: Well if you can't get into the bios I don't see how you are going to be able to do anything because you can't format a HDD that isn't plugged in.